# py_tesseract doesnt recognize numbers in this image

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to use py-tesseract on google colabs to parse the following image containing readings from a meter. However it fails to get me the result expected. Looks like i need to do some pre-processing on the image. I am new to py-tesseract. Can you please help what i need to do to get this to work?

Here is my current code followed by output seen and the image:

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
!pip install pytesseract

import pytesseract
import shutil
import os
import random
try:
 from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
 import Image

image_path='drive/MyDrive/cropped_image.jpg'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image_path, config='--psm 13 --oem=3'))
```

Output

```
ey
```

Image being parsed
[Cropped_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKiJi.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image_path, config='-1 eng --oem 2 --psm 12'))
```

**Output:**

```
194735787
```

Comment: Thank you Nikunj Bansal. That worked.

I was also looking at, if its possible to print the numbers below that as well: "0040550"

Would that need more adjustments in terms of oem/psm or some image pre-processing?

I was thinking of writing this to generically read such meter reading and do some further processing. But sounds like based on the picture the oem/psm values have to be custom adjusted. Is that true?

Comment: @nn_user1982 Good to know. It helped you. I'm not sure about that. But I think you need image pre-processing to read the below number.

Comment: Others, please help.

The above answer helped me partially. However i am looking for 2 more things:

1) How do i get the second number in the image parsed (0040550)?
2) Can i write a generic application that can be fed similar images (with different readings off course) that can parse the digits. I am ok if the image needs some pre-processing etc. 

I am new to this. Please guide if you have prior experience doing such things.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to preprocess the image which helps to reduce the noise and help in text extraction.

- Extract text area from the image
- Convert the image to grayscale and sharpen the image
- Apply adaptive threshold
- Clean the image by performing morphological operations and invert the image

```html
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('qKiJi.jpg')
#crop the text extraction area
crop = img[200:350, 100:400]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, sharpen_kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
result = 255 - close
cv2.imshow('img', crop)
cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Cropping the image]

[image]

[image]